# Spring: Date Binding in the format dd/MM/yyyy i.e. 31/12/1999

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

You may find this as duplicate question, still I'm not getting what is wrong with following code.

This code I found in several WebSites and in Spring Documentation , any ty-po here in my code ?

I want persist object in file (.ser) , which contains several 'Date' fields, and show details again in my jsp,

The formart requred to me is dd/MM/yyyy i.e. 31/12/1999.

It shows in the format "Wed Jun 01 00:00:00 IST 2016" before persisting in my controller.
I have used CustomDateEditor as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
```

in above code I have used two parameters to registerCustomEditor() , is this ok ? 
or how to do for multiple fields ,

```
webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
```

should I have to use this above line of code for every field.

I have tried for this one also but no success

```
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new PropertyEditorSupport(){
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            System.out.println(text+"  setAsText");
            try {
                if( text != "")
                    //setValue(text);
                    setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(value));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 setValue(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
            System.out.println(getValue()+" getValue");
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").format((Date)getValue());
        }
    });
```

In my JSP , I used date picker as:

```
    $('#id-scheme-start-date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    });
```

I have another choice to use JSTL tag in JSP but I do not want to use this at several position.

Comment: Where does this get printed out: "Wed Jun 01 00:00:00 IST 2016" ? In this codeline: `System.out.println(text+"  setAsText");`?

Comment: no, Here at that line my date got printed correctlly in the format dd/MM/yyyy same as the input text field...
"Wed Jun 01 00:00:00 IST 2016" got printed in my controller's handle before persisiting ...